# Visual Studio SFML tutorial graphics not displaying properly

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I'm not sure if this is a problem with Visual Studio (I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017) or SFML. I've followed the configuration process on https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/start-vc.php and used their tutorial code. SFML is indeed configured but test graphic image is not displaying correctly according to the tutorial, and everything seems stretched vertically.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I can only confirm that the circle is displayed correctly on my machine. I am not using Visual Studio and used your posted code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a notebook with dual-GPU, then your Intel GPU driver is outdated and it has a bug, where it would setup the OpenGL "drawing area" on a window wrongly. Alternatively, you can force your application to run on the dedicated GPU.